# using conda over ssh from powershell script

Tags: powershell, conda

I want to create powershell script that connects my remote pc. It is supposed to activate a conda environment and run a jupyter notebook from activated environment. My initial script looks like this:

```
$number = 6
$i = 1
$remoteComputer = "xxxxxxxx"

do {
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    $i++ 
    IF (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Quiet) {
        ssh $remoteComputer  "conda activate test; jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888"
        ssh -N -f -L localhost:8889:localhost:8888 $remoteComputer
        break
    }   
}while ($i -le $number)
```

The line with conda activate throws `activate does not accept more than one argument`
Notes:

- Paths to my environments does not contain spaces
- I can run other commands. For example ssh $remoteComputer "dir" works.
- Both local and remote computer uses windows.

Comment: Maybe try a `&&` instead of `;` to separate commands. Or better, don't rely on shell, and use `conda run -n test jupyter notebook ...`. You'll likely need one of the additional `conda run` flags to enable interactive I/O (see `conda run -h`).

Comment: Yes, conda run works thanks